# How do they film minors smoking?

Tags: film-techniques

Many movies depict children and minors (and non smoking actors) actively smoking a cigarette and blowing actual smoke. How is that done?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Actually the film makers claim that the cigarettes used by the minors are **tobacco-free cigarettes** or **nicotine-free cigarettes**. They are commonly called **herbal cigarette.**

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbal_cigarette),

> Herbal cigarettes are also used in acting scenes by performers who
>   are non-smokers, or -- as is becoming increasingly common -- where
>   anti-smoking legislation prohibits the use of tobacco in public
>   spaces.Herbal cigarettes are not viewed as physically addictive, as they do not contain addictive substances.

[image: picture of packet of herbal cigarettes]

Answer (score 18):

One of the more famous scenes of a young actress smoking is Tatum O'Neal in Paper Moon:

[This article](http://forever-starlet.livejournal.com/6121.html) quotes her as saying:

> "Peter [Bogdanovich, the director] wanted me to smoke in the movie,
>   but the cigarettes were filled with lettuce, not tabacco. They glued
>   sandpaper to my fingers so I could strike a match one-handed."

It also has discussions of the following other young actresses:

- Natalie Portman in Leon: The Professional
- Thora Birch in Now and Then
- Dakota Fanning in Hounddog
- Kiernan Shipka on Mad Men
- AnnaSophia Robb in Sleepwalking

As mentioned in another answer, they almost all mention some type of herbal cigarettes.

Comment: Peter Bogdanovich has recorded an audio commentary to Paper Moon, included as a bonus feature on the DVD, in which he explains the same points here attributed to Tatum O'Neil.

Answer (score -7):

I think the actors suck the smoke only into their mouths, but not into their lungs so it doesn't do damage to the lungs.

Comment: but how do they keep from increasing the chances of mouth cancer, if they are using real cigarettes, with tobacco and nicotine?

Comment: @CGCampbell You don't get cancer from a few cigarettes (not that I would approve of having kids smoking under any condition, btw.)

Comment: Would it be fair to say that they didn't inhale?