# What if an actor doesn’t smoke?

Tags: film-techniques, props

What if a scene calls for an actor to pull out a cigarette and light up? But the actor isn’t a smoker?

Are there fake cigarette props? Vapor cigs that don’t have any nicotine or harm to the lungs?

How does that typically work? Please no “do you know Hollywood culture?” answers. I’m asking for serious answers.

Comment: Related (if not even duplicate): [How do they film minors smoking?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/2620/49)

Comment: This is not a question about minors. This is a question about ALL actors in general.

Comment: Well, same problem, though. Just that in the case of minors it's not a question of preference rather than law, but the issue is the same.

Comment: While not the exact same wording, this is essentially just a more generalized way of asking the same question. And ultimately has the same answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I believe they simply don't inhale. I have noticed many actors before not inhaling. This would not be the case for everyone though. The actor should know before hand that it's a smoking role and chose to take it or not. The director may wish the smoking character to inhale for realism and some negociating with the actor in some cases would have happened. I guess the money on offer for the role would also play a part in the actors decision.

Comment: You missed the whole point. The main point is **they don't use tobacco**.

Comment: This is all nice and well, but can you back this up somehow? Currently it reads largely like your own speculation.

Comment: No, the main question is what if the actor is not a smoker but is asked to light one up. My answer is an honest one. I could back up my answer by posting various examples of movies where the actor isn't inhaling, but I don't have the time and believe anyone seriously interested in this answer would bother to look for themselves. I know myself I am correct as I have seen it many time for myself.

Comment: As for tobacco free cigerettes, they are just as harmful on the lungs, they just don't have nicotene to help already smokers quit. Not inhaling is the best way. Also, it's a pretty obvious "speculation" as there are no other solutions or scenarios possible, except maybe cgi smoke, but who would bother?

Comment: I could back my argument up with a) years of experience in the film industry & b) it's actually illegal to smoke tobacco indoors in many countries. The question of whether one type of cigarette is more harmful than the other is actually moot. One is illegal, the other you can smoke anywhere so long as 'management' allows it.

Comment: Sorry, I admit I was only considering America and Europe which have laws that allow smoking inside if it's for creative purposes such as theatre and movies.